# Git hangs while cloning through ssh

Tags: git, github, ssh

I had recently installed Fedora 26, and set up SSH keys with github.

I was able to authenticate and push, pull and clone through ssh.

But now whenever I execute a clone command, git just hangs there at `Cloning into 'Blog'...`

This is the output of `ssh -Tvv git@github.com`

```
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0f-fips  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 8: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.255.113] port 22.
```

And hangs, no error message no ouput anymore.

Here is my `**ssh-config**`

```
# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

# Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
#
# To modify the system-wide ssh configuration, create a  *.conf  file under
#  /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/  which will be automatically included below
Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf
```

How do I fix this?

P.S Comment any additional information needed

Comment: Does this occur while cloning any repository, or upon cloning particular repo?

Comment: This occurs for all repositories, and for all git functions( clone , push, pull)

Comment: Do you have any file matching `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf`? Is there something concerning GitHub in one of them?

Comment: The same works for me just fine. Can you try once more? Are you able to connect to github using your browser? Can you clone using https?

Comment: I just tested it, and it's not just GitHub. I cannot connect to any site via ssh. It just hangs at connecting and after sometime shows connection timed out

Comment: I can execute ssh localhost just fine

Comment: So after 2 days, it fixed itself as if by magic. I am forced to assume that it might have been the trouble with my ISP.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a while before stumbling onto a help page buried under GitHub support:

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

Turns out my workplace had just the right magic combination of firewall/port protection to "almost" allow regular Git SSH access to GitHub, i.e. it worked "occasionally" but not reliably. ;-b

With this incantation in my $HOME/.ssh/config file, to use SSH Over HTTPS, I was suddenly able to access my GitHub repo from the command line via my SSH Key in GitHub:

```
Host github.com
    User git
    Hostname ssh.github.com
    Port 443
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /home/XXX/.ssh/github_id_rsa
    TCPKeepAlive yes     # not sure if truly needed
    IdentitiesOnly yes   # not sure if truly needed
```